# Why is my HTTP response both 502 on my side but 401 on the server?

Tags: json, http, error-code, http-response-codes

I am making an HTTP POST of a JSON from an Android app to my server (server code was not set by myself).

Most of the times this works correctly and I get a response of 200. However sometimes I get a 502 error code on the phone, but it logs as a 401 error code on the server.

The JSON is generated using unknown data from another source, however I have reviewed the JSON and it appears to be correct. The issue has only been seen when the JSON is particularly big.

Below is the code to set credentials and attach JSON to the HTTP post:

```
            //set httpClient
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

            //create http post
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServerURL);

            //TODO SET THE JSON
            try {
                JSONObject thisObject = new JSONObject(query);
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(thisObject.toString());
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
            }
            catch (JSONException ex)
            {
                longInfo("JSONException - JSON error" + ex.getMessage(), 0);
            }
```

Why are the error codes different? Is it because the credentials are not verified by the server when it gets a 401 error?

Is there a common cause for this pairing of error codes which is known?

(NOTE the username and password are definitely correct as they are successful when sending small JSON file)

Comment: Is there a proxy in between?

Comment: ^ Nginx reverse proxy? My guess is that your webserver is returning a 502 because it can't access your backend app container due to a authentication error, which i why you see 401 in the logs.

Comment: @Thilo - there is no proxy that I am aware of. The server is hosted by openhost, and we are renting server space of them so they could have put a proxy in.

Comment: @doublesharp could this authentication error be a result of delays in authentication process by larger JSON files?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that we have just tested an identical file transfer from our iOS version of the app (I am NOT the developer for iOS) and the upload was successful (200)

Comment: If you see a different HTTP code on the client than the server I would have to assume their is a front end proxy routing to whatever your app layer is written in. The 502 error means that it can't access a gateway (your app). The server is seeing the request, but sending a 401 which really should be routed back to the client, and since it's not I'm guessing the issue is with the front end communicating with the app layer. Hard to say without more details.

Comment: Longer times could result in a timeout, but I wouldn't necessarily expect to see a 502 or 401 in that case.

Comment: I have the same problem. Whenever our token expires the server throws 401 error but the client receives 502